# Language Switching and Page Routing Issue in HTML Header

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ejs

I'm encountering an issue with language switching and page routing in the header of my HTML website. I've implemented a header with language options and navigation links, but the language switching and page routing behavior doesn't work as expected.

Here's a breakdown of the problem and the relevant code snippets:

Problem Description:

- Language Switching: I have language links (EN and BG) in my header that should allow users to switch between English and Bulgarian versions of the website.
- Page Routing: When a user clicks on a navigation link like "Contact", they should be routed to the appropriate language version of the Contact page (e.g., /contact/en or /contact/bg).

Current Behavior:

- When the homepage language is set to Bulgarian and I click on "Contact", it routes me to the English version of the Contact page instead of the Bulgarian version of the Contact page.
- Additionally, when I attempt to change the language on the Contact page to Bulgarian, it routes me back to the Bulgarian version of the homepage.

Relevant Code Snippets:

```
<header
  id="header"
  class="header--has-languages header--has-search header--has-cta header--has-contact header--has-social-links header--has-collision-detection header--has-expanded-panel"
  style="
    background-image: url('https://demo.lsvr.sk/html/beautyspot/images/header_bg.jpg');
  "
>
  <div class="header__inner">
    <div class="header__content">
      <!-- HEADER LANGUAGES : begin -->
      <div class="header-languages">
        <span class="screen-reader-text">Choose language</span>
        <ul class="header-languages__list">
          <li class="header-languages__item header-languages__item--active">
            <a href="#en" class="header-languages__item-link">EN</a>
          </li>

          <!-- Inside the header-languages__list -->
          <li class="header-languages__item">
            <a href="#bg" class="header-languages__item-link">BG</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <button
          type="button"
          class="header-languages__toggle"
          title="Choose language"
        >
          <span
            class="header-languages__toggle-icon icon-close"
            aria-hidden="true"
          ></span>
          <span class="header-languages__toggle-label">EN</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <!-- HEADER LANGUAGES : end -->

      <!-- HEADER BRANDING : begin -->
      <div class="header-branding">
        <div class="header-branding__inner">
          <!-- HEADER LOGO : begin -->
          <div class="header-logo">
            <a href="http://localhost:4000" class="header-logo__link">
              <img
                src="/images/logo.png"
                class="header-logo__image"
                alt="Logo"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- HEADER LOGO : end -->

          <!-- HEADER TITLE TAGLINE : begin -->
          <div class="header-title-tagline">
            <div class="header-title">
              <a href="http://localhost:4000" class="header-title__link"
                >BeautySpot</a
              >
            </div>

            <p class="header-tagline">HTML Template for Beauty Salons</p>
          </div>
          <!-- HEADER TITLE TAGLINE : end -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- HEADER BRANDING : end -->

      <!-- HEADER MENU : begin -->
      <nav class="header-menu" aria-label="Header menu">
        <ul class="header-menu__list" role="menu">
          <!-- MENU ITEM : begin -->
          <li
            class="header-menu__item header-menu__item<%= (selection == 'home' && '--current') %> header-menu__item <% menu.items.home.length > 0 && --has-children %>"
          >
            <span class="header-menu__item-link-wrapper">
              <a
                href="<%= menu.items.home.hrefs[0]%>"
                class="header-menu__item-link"
                >Home</a
              >
            </span>

            <% if(menu.items.home.length > 0) { %>

            <button
              type="button"
              class="header-menu__submenu-toggle"
              title="Expand submenu"
            >
              <span
                class="header-menu__submenu-toggle-icon"
                aria-hidden="true"
              ></span>
            </button>

            <ul class="header-menu__submenu">
              <li class="header-menu__item header-menu__item--current">
                <a
                  href="index.html"
                  class="header-menu__item-link"
                  role="menuitem"
                  >Home 1</a
                >
              </li>

              <li class="header-menu__item">
                <a
                  href="index-2.html"
                  class="header-menu__item-link"
                  role="menuitem"
                  >Home 2</a
                >
              </li>
            </ul>
            <% }; %>
          </li>
          <!-- MENU ITEM : end -->

          <!-- MENU ITEM : begin -->
          <li
            class="header-menu__item header-menu__item<%= (selection == 'services' && '--current') %>"
          >
            <span class="header-menu__item-link-wrapper">
              <a
                href="<%= menu.items.services.hrefs[0] %>"
                class="header-menu__item-link"
                >Our Services</a
              >
            </span>
          </li>
          <!-- MENU ITEM : end -->

          <!-- MENU ITEM : begin -->
          <li
            class="header-menu__item header-menu__item<%= (selection == 'store' && '--current') %> <% menu.items.store.length > 0 && --has-children %>"
          >
            <span class="header-menu__item-link-wrapper">
              <a
                href="<%= menu.items.store.hrefs[0] %>"
                class="header-menu__item-link"
                >Store</a
              >
            </span>

            <% if(menu.items.store.length > 0) { %>

            <button
              type="button"
              class="header-menu__submenu-toggle"
              title="Expand submenu"
            >
              <span
                class="header-menu__submenu-toggle-icon"
                aria-hidden="true"
              ></span>
            </button>

            <ul class="header-menu__submenu">
              <li class="header-menu__item">
                <a
                  href="product-archive.html"
                  class="header-menu__item-link"
                  role="menuitem"
                  >Products</a
                >
              </li>

              <li class="header-menu__item">
                <a
                  href="http://localhost:4000/cart"
                  class="header-menu__item-link"
                  role="menuitem"
                  >Cart</a
                >
              </li>

              <li class="header-menu__item">
                <a
                  href="product-checkout.html"
                  class="header-menu__item-link"
                  role="menuitem"
                  >Checkout</a
                >
              </li>
            </ul>

            <% }; %>
          </li>
          <!-- MENU ITEM : end -->

          <!-- MENU ITEM : begin -->
          <li
            class="header-menu__item header-menu__item--has-children header-menu__item<%= (selection == 'about us' && '--current') %>"
          >
            <span class="header-menu__item-link-wrapper">
              <a
                href="<%= menu.items.about.hrefs[0] %>"
                class="header-menu__item-link"
                >About Us</a
              >
            </span>

            <button
              type="button"
              class="header-menu__submenu-toggle"
              title="Expand submenu"
            >
              <span
                class="header-menu__submenu-toggle-icon"
                aria-hidden="true"
              ></span>
            </button>

            <ul class="header-menu__submenu">
              <% if(menu.items.about.submenus.length > 0) { %> <% for(let i = 0;
              i < menu.items.about.submenus.length; i++) { %>
              <li class="header-menu__item">
                <a
                  href="<%= menu.items.about.hrefs[i] %>"
                  class="header-menu__item-link"
                  role="menuitem"
                >
                  <%= menu.items.about.submenus[i] %>
                </a>
              </li>
              <% } %> <% } %>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!-- MENU ITEM : end -->

          <!-- MENU ITEM : begin -->
          <li
            class="header-menu__item header-menu__item<%= (selection == 'contact' && '--current') %>"
          >
            <span class="header-menu__item-link-wrapper">
              <a
                href="<%= menu.items.contacts.hrefs[0] %>"
                class="header-menu__item-link"
                >Contact</a
              >
            </span>
          </li>
```

This below is my endpoint in `app.js`:

```
app.get("/contact/:lang?", async (req, res) => {
  let lang = req.params.lang === "bg" ? "bg" : "en"; // Default to English if language parameter is not provided or not 'bg'

  // Load JSON file for contact based on the selected language
  const contactJSON = require(`./json/${lang}/contact.json`);

  // Load header and footer HTML content
  const headerHtml = await renderAsync("components/header", {
      menu: menuJson,
      selection: "contact",
  });
  const footerHtml = await renderAsync("components/footer", {
      info: footerJson,
  });

  // Render the contact page with appropriate content and HTML
  res.status(200).render("contact", {
      details: contactJSON,
      html: {
          header: headerHtml,
          footer: footerHtml,
      },
  });
});
```

Additional Context:

- The website is built using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.
- I've tried adjusting the language links and routing logic but haven't been able to resolve the issue.
- The website is hosted locally using a development server.
- I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to fix this language switching and page routing issue in the header. Thank you in advance for your help!